# Combobox Dependientes

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

Estoy tratando de que al seleccionar un ítem en un combobox, un segundo combobox cambie su contenido. Estos ítems están siendo llamados con una consulta de LINQ a un SQL server, estoy usando los eventos DropDownClosed y SelectionChanged, pero no consigo entender al total el SelectionChanged

```
    private void CbxIdTipoEventoContrato_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var comboGuardado = cbxIdTipoEventoContrato.SelectedItem as string;
        if(comboGuardado.Equals("Coffee Break") 
        {
            Brick.OnBreakEntities bbdd = new Brick.OnBreakEntities();
            var llenarCoffee = (from mod in bbdd.ModalidadServicio
                                where mod.IdTipoEvento.Equals(10)
                                select new { idt = mod.IdTipoEvento, nomb = mod.Nombre }).ToList();



            cbxIdModalidadContrato.ItemsSource = llenarCoffee;
            cbxIdModalidadContrato.SelectedValuePath = "idt";
            cbxIdModalidadContrato.DisplayMemberPath = "nomb"; 

        }


    }
```

Al seleccionar Coffee Break, me arroja un error en el if que indica que la excepción no se cumplió

Comment: Podrias poner el mensaje real que recibes de la exception, porque no suena a nada eso del "no se cumplio"